# Tennyson quote in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I need help translating a Tennyson line

> Be loyal to the royal in
> thyself and be loyal to the
> land

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal translation is straightforward enough:

**Es fidelis regio in te ipse et es fidelis terrae.**

N.B. that *es* is a 2nd person singular imperative here, and that *regio* is the dative of *regium* (I interpreted *royal* as a general royal quality, not as if the person addressed is literally a member of the royal family; *fidelis* takes either the dative or *in* + accusative). If you want to make it *thy land* instead of *the land*, add *tuae* after *terrae*.

Other choices could be made; this doesn't preserve Tennyson's internal rhyme or rhythm, but a high-quality poetic translation is probably beyond the scope of the Latin Language Stack Exchange.

Comment: One grammatical issue: it should be *ipso* (ablative), not *ipse* (nominative).

Comment: @brianpck I think both are correct (that is, *ipse* outside of its use specifically as a demonstrative pronoun can be declined or treated as indeclinable)? I had Seneca's famous line *"recede in te ipse quantum potes"* in mind (*te* in the accusative, *ipse* not declined), but *in te ipso* is obviously not wrong.

Comment: Though looking it up now I see the Loeb edition has *ipsum* there.

Comment: I looked it up [here](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/demonstrative-pronouns) (298f) and found something new: apparently *ipse* often agrees with the (understood) subject. So, in your case, *ipse* would agree with the understood nominative *tu* of the imperative--which isn't quite the same as being indeclinable.

Comment: Oh, cool, I never knew that. Happy accident, then.